# English translation of Sung-Dae Hong's The Art of Mathematics

Tags: secondary-education, textbooks, reference-books

*The Art of Mathematics* by Sung-Dae Hong is the standard high-school mathematics textbook in South Korea. The series gets new editions and reprints since 1966. Wikipedia has a [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Mathematics) for it.

Had it ever been translated into English? I've checked the Library of Congress and Amazon, without success. Maybe there's a manuscript that has not been officially published?

Comment: Well, https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486450201?tag=duckduckgo-d-20&linkCode=osi&th=1&psc=1 is definitely not it.

Answer (score 2):

I found a series of textbooks on Amazon entitled *Oh Math!* with subtitles which seem to match The Art of Mathematics by Hong. These were written by Chris Cho. I can't see too much with the preview, but it seems they are half Korean half English. It might be what you want. At a minimum, take a look:

[The English Korean OH! MATH Probability-Statistics textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1520530714)

Incidentally, searching "OH! MATH" or "OH MATH" does not help.

Comment: I contacted Chris Cho. He told me that _The Art of Mathematics_ and _Oh! Math_ have the same structure because it's the high school math curriculum standardized by the Korean government. He also said Hong's series has not been translated into English.

Comment: @AntonTarasenko well, you should have Cho post here so you can accept his answer :)